# Prove that a normal group of index $k $ contains all elements whose order is coprime with $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'd appreciate any help with this:

> Let $G$ be a group and $H \subset G$ normal. If $[G:N] = k$, then $H$
>   contains all elements $h$ such that $\mathbb{gcd}(k, o(h)) = 1$.

What I know:

- If $H$ is normal in $G$, then $\forall g \in G \implies gH = Hg$.
- $[G:H] = k$, is the number of distinct cosets of $H$.
- The order of an element $h \in H$ is the smallest positive integer
  $m$ such that $h^m = e$. So we have that $\mathbb{gcd}(k, m) = 1$.

We also have that $[G:H] = \frac{|G|}{|H|} = k$. But I don't even know how to begin ):

Comment: Please, fix the question: you seem to have $N$ where $H$ should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$, with $[G:N]=k$ and let $x\in G$, with $o(x)=n$ and $\gcd(k,n)=1$.

The element $x$ generates a subgroup $H=\langle x\rangle$ of $G$ with order $n$. So, if $\pi\colon G\to G/N$, then $|\pi(H)|$ is a divisor of $n$ and $k$, hence $|\pi(H)|=1$. Since
$$
\pi(H)=\frac{HN}{N}\cong \frac{H}{N\cap H}
$$
by the homomorphism theorem, we conclude $N\cap H=H$. In particular, $x\in N$.

Comment: Pretty neat!!. I was also trying to construct a map, but I didn't know how to go about it. Why $|\pi(H)| = 1$ ? And why is this: $\pi(H)=\frac{HN}{N}\cong \frac{H}{N\cap H}$?

Comment: @Jazz If $G$ is a group of order $n$, then $f(G)$ has order a divisor of $n$, if $f\colon G\to G'$ is a group homomorphism; it also has order a divisor of $|G'|$: both follow from Lagrange’s theorem. The second part is just the homomorphism theorem.

Comment: I got the part that $|f(G)|$ is a divisor of $|G'|$ (since $f(G) \subset G'$ and, as you said, follows from Lagrange's Theorem). So I understand why $|\pi(H)|$ is a divisor of $k$. The part I didn't quite get is this: It was supposed that $|H| = n$  but why the order of $G$ is $n$?. I know that $\mathrm{Ker}( \pi )\subset G$ , but how did you apply Lagrange's Theorem to conclude that $|\pi(H)|$ also divides $n$?

Comment: Just now I got the other part. Better late than never.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\;g\in G\;$ has order $\;m\;$ coprime with $\;[G:H]=k\;$, then in the quotient group

$$(gH)^m=eH=H\implies g^m\in H\;\;\ldots$$

Try to finish the argument now, perhaps using that there exist integers $\;x,y\;$ s.t. $\;xk+ym=1\;$ ...

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $[G:H]=k$.
Let $g\in G$ where $|g|=n$ where$(k,n)=1$
By Bezout's Theorem, $xk+yn=1$ for some integer $x,y$.
Then $$gH=g^{xk+yn}H=g^{xk}H=(gH)^{xk}=H$$
Hence we conclude that $g\in H$

Remark
Since $[G:H]=k$ and $H\lhd G$, $(gH)^k=H$ for any $g\in G$